# Mutating Error in Oracle trigger

Tags: oracle

Help, I am very new to oracle trigger. 
What I trying to do is when delete C last row of B, A shall not have B.
So I create a trigger on C.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER child_check    
 BEFORE DELETE DELETE ON C

   REFERENCING OLD as OLD   
FOR EACH ROW DECLARE    
rowcnt number;  
rowcnt1 number;

BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO rowcnt FROM C WHERE colB = :OLD.colB;
    IF rowcnt > 1 THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DELETE');
        DELETE C WHERE ROWID = :OLD.ROWID;
    ELSE
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO rowcnt1 FROM A WHERE colB = :OLD.colB;
        IF rowcnt1 > 1 THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('B IS USED IN A. C CANNOT REMOVE ALL OF B');
            ELSE
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DELETE');
            DELETE C WHERE ROWID = :OLD.ROWID;
            DELETE B WHERE colB = :OLD.colB;
        END IF;      
        END IF;

END; /

   TABLE A    | TABLE B |   TABLE C
colA  | colB  |  colB   | colC | colB
```

> A.colA is PK 
>   B.colB is PK 
>   C.colC is PK
>
> A.colB FK of B.colB 
>   C.colB FK of B.colB

There is a mutating error.
I do a google search and I understand there is something got to do with the delete. I cannot find a concrete solution
Can someone enlighten me how and what to change in the delete query?

Comment: You're trying to delete the same table where the trigger is firing... I don't see why you're trying to do that?

Comment: Are you looking for [foreign keys with cascade delete](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php) instead of a trigger?

Comment: Hi I have add the table for better understanding.
There is a restrict on delete constrain check on C and A, So If I need to delete any data from B, C and A as child have to delete before I can delete B.
What I need is. I want to delete C. but if data in C is last record, I have to make sure A do not have B before allowing C last record to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle you cannot perform select, insert, update or delete on the table the row level trigger is on. In your case the trigger is on C so you are not allowed to delete records from C.

Your trigger seems a bit strange. The trigger fires when a record is deleted from C. And then the trigger is also deleting that record from C. That is not necessary. The record will be deleted.

Deleting from B is possible.

Your code is hard to understand. B is a column in C but also the name of a table? Very confusing.

Comment: Sorry, there is a foreign key constrain delete on restrict. B cannot be delete if A or C is present.

Comment: Specification: I a **ROW LEVEL** Trigger (with `FOR EACH ROW` clause) you  cannot perform DML or SELECT on the table the trigger is on. `SELECT` is not a DML. There are exceptoins: [Why am I NOT getting a mutating table error in trigger?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29244/why-am-i-not-getting-a-mutating-table-error-in-trigger)

Answer (score 0):

Also apart from `Mutating Trigger` error this could also cause the triggers to execute recursively and fail, as your `Delete` (on `c`) statement in the `trigger` would start an other `trigger` and this happens repeatedly.